# Autofac BeginLifetimeScope

Tags: c#, autofac

I create a processing object as follows during the start of a process:

```
using (var lifetime = EngineContext.Current.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var sourceService = lifetime.Resolve<SourceService>();  
    // do things... 
}
```

The SourceService class depends on other objects also registered with AutoFac - through constructor injection.

Do these objects automatically inherit the same lifetimescope as its 'parent' i.e. sourceService ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how they were registered.

`InstancePerLifetimeScope` = one  per scope.

Example:

```
builder.Register<YourClass>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

You can read more here:

http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html

Comment: ...and the default, InstancePerDependency(), results in scope-local instances, too.